# Remove "&" from input stream when generating XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];

// If file.InputSteam contains an "&", exception is thrown
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(file.InputStream)); 

HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(doc);
```

Is there any way to replace `&` with `&amp;` before generating the xml document? My current code crashes whenever the file contains a `&`.

Thanks

Comment: `&` indicates the start of an character reference, if what follows it isn't a valid reference then the XML parser should throw an exception. It sounds like you problem is that people are submitting things that are not XML. Don't discard bits of data, catch the exception and return an error message to the uploader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will only crash if it's not valid XML. For example, this should be fine:

```
<foo>A &amp; B</foo>
```

If you've *actually* got

```
<foo>A & B</foo>
```

Then you haven't got an XML file. You may have something which looks a bit like XML, but it isn't really valid XML.

The best approach here isn't to transform the data on the fly - it's to fix the *source* of the data so that it's real XML. There's really no excuse for anything producing invalid XML in this day and age.

Additionally, there's no reason to use `XmlReader.Create` here - just use

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file.InputStream);
```

Comment: Is there any other characters but the `&` that i should be aware of? Since its based on user input in text fields, characters like the `&` might occur. But I suppose the best way is to htmlencode the input fields before generating the xml?

Comment: @Johan: How is this XML being generated? It sounds like you're probably using string concatenation... **don't**. Use an XML API to produce the file to start with, and it will be fine. You should really provide more context about the bigger picture here.

Comment: The xml is generated from a json string using JSON.NET. The json object itself contains input data from an html form.

Comment: @Johan: So you've got some JSON... but what's turning that into XML? (Is it really XML at all, or is it just JSON?) That's where the problem is. Again, please provide much more context - and edit it into your question instead of just adding comments.

Comment: As i said, JSON.NET is turning it in to an xml. But ive got enough info from you and the other comments to solve my issue. Thanks

Comment: @Johan: For future questions, please include all the relevant code... I'd be surprised if json.net itself was producing invalid XML.

Comment: "There's really no excuse for anything producing invalid XML in this day and age." I agree completely. Sadly common sense is not enough to prevent bad source of data everywhere...

Answer (score 0):

use `HttpEncoder.HtmlEncode()`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.util.httpencoder.aspx

Comment: Ok, but what would i use it on? I cant use it on the stream, right?`

Answer (score 0):

you can use "& amp;" to escape "&".

In xml document, there are some characters should be escaped.

```
& ---- &amp;

< ---- &lt;

> ---- &gt;

" ---- &quot;

' ---- &apos;
```